# Is this a valid code fix for strict-aliasing rule break?

Tags: c

I'm wanting to build/burn the latest Mellanox Flexboot firmware to my Infiniband ConnectX-3 cards.  However, Mellanox have not provided the latest version in binary form.  They do however supply the source code.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to compile it I get the following error:

```
net/udp/dhcp.c: In function 'start_dhcp':
net/udp/dhcp.c:1361:3: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
   seed += *( ( uint32_t * )&netdev->ll_addr[j] );
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [bin/dhcp.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Build failed!
```

Looking at the code, the following block is the problem. Specifically the seed line.  And it's because strict aliasing is on and we're trying to access one type as another.

```
/**
 * Having both i and j , makes the code more robust
 * in the improbable case that MAX_LL_ADDR_LEN is not a
 * multiple of 4 bytes.
 */
for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < ( MAX_LL_ADDR_LEN >> 2 ); ++i, j += 4 ){
   seed += *( ( uint32_t * )&netdev->ll_addr[j] );
}
```

My fix which makes it compile.

```
for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < ( MAX_LL_ADDR_LEN >> 2 ); ++i, j += 4 ){
   uint32_t s;
   memcpy(&s, &netdev->ll_addr[j], 4);
   seed += s;
}
```

But before I burn it, is this actually equivalent?  I think it should be but I'm just wanting a second opinion before I burn something so important.

FYI:
ll_addr is defined as:

```
#define MAX_LL_ADDR_LEN 20

...

/** Link-layer address
 *
 * This is the current link-layer address assigned to the      
 * device.  It can be changed at runtime.
 */
 uint8_t ll_addr[MAX_LL_ADDR_LEN];
```

Seed is later used here:

```
 dhcp->xid = random ( seed );

 /* Store DHCP transaction ID for fakedhcp code */
 dhcp_last_xid = dhcp->xid;
```

So it looks to me this seed thing is just used to seed the random number generator.  I'm not really sure if the way they seed it is a terribly good idea, but nontheless it shouldn't harm things and I think my fix should be fine even if it gave out a different answer.  So thanks folks for the answers.

Comment: They should be, if the original code actually worked.  The code on the bottom should even work if `uint32_t` has stricter alignment rules, whereas the code on top might not.  Also be sure the field stores the bytes in the same endian-order, which data from a disk or network might not.  If I were being very pedantic about portability or coding style, I might suggest changing the magic number 4 to a `sizeof`.

Comment: That looks quite like a hack. They should have used proper (de-)serialization. Very likely there are other such constructs.

Comment: It looks like it is a hardware address, probably the way I'm accessing it is fine.  It should be equivalent to the previous hacky code I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're safe, so long as `ll_addr` is an array of `char`. The increment of `j` guarantees that the incrementation will only be performed four bytes at a time, which is the width of `uint32_t`.

In this case, it may be better to use the original implementation and ignore the error, especially if the code was written prior to C99.

Lorehead also makes a good point regarding endianness.